# How can I prevent an assignment statement to CheckBox.Checked from raising the CheckChanged event?

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, controls

Given

```
    Dim cb As CheckBox = New CheckBox
    AddHandler cb, AddressOf cb_CheckChanged
    cb.Checked = True
```

...aside from disabling the control, how can I prevent the assignment to Checked from raising the  CheckChanged event?  I grew up in MFC and events only got raised when the U S E R changed the control's state.  What was Softy was thinking?  Is it really impossible to distinguish between an event from the user and an event from my own assignment statement?  *Yikes!*

Comment: If it's a one time thing (e.g. you're drawing the GUI with default states), just swap the second and third line of code. Otherwise it's funny that you try to blame MS for making a perfectly logical implementation.

Comment: "*Is it really impossible to distinguish between a user and my assignment statement?*"  Not at all hard, your assignment statement is the one that can disable the control (or its handlers) when it needs to change the control and then re-enable them when its done.  The real question is why can't your code tell the difference between itself and a user?

Comment: Actually, disabling the control does not prevent the raise either.  Therefore I am forced to litter my code with ugly booleans.  This is especially troublesome with check boxes and radio buttons.  I do fault softy on this design change relative to MFC.  I base this on 30 years of experience.

Comment: Those 30 years of doing it the same way isn't helping you right now.  The approach in .NET is fundamentally different from the way it works in Windows, a much stronger model for the observer pattern with anybody able to observe.  Including code that's entirely oblivious that it was your code that changed the checked state instead of the user.  If you have a bunch of bool flags then you are doing it wrong.  Only way to get the brain transplant you'll need is to strive to get rid of them.

Answer (score 2):

it is perfectly valid to raise the event regardless of the thing causing the event because the `CheckChanged` event just tells you when the `Checked` property has changed.

If you are trying to avoid the infinite loop you must be experiencing try adding a conditional:

```
If Not cb.Checked Then
  cb.Checked = True
End If
```